# Lotus Notes create email folder

Tags: vba, lotus-notes

Goal: excel macro that creates a new lotus notes email subfolder

I am totally new when it comes to VBA and Lotus Notes in general.
I would appreciate if smb would indicate some directions in achieving my goal, because until know I wasn't able to find anything similar.

1) how do I connect to needed mail (regarding this I saw some info, but a clear code example would be great)

2) how do I create the subfolder with a specified name and indicate the folder where it should be created

Comment: On this site, you need to show people that you've tried to solve the problem yourself and ask specific questions about things you don't understand or which do not work the way you expect. I suggest that you search on Google for "Lotus Notes VBA folder", find some examples, try them, and then try to modify them to fit your specific needs. If you have problems, then come back here to stackOverflow, post your code, tell us what it does, tell us what you want it to do differently, tell us what you understand and what you don't understand, and ask more specific questions.

Comment: Your answer is helpful for sure) 

I searched all over, but I can't seem to find any indications about what classes can be used in order to control the mail folder architecture, for being able to add delete, rename or anything regarding folder management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API for a folder architechture because there really is no folder architecture. Nested folders are an illusion just based on the name of the folder.  I.e., the folder name "folder1\folder2" indicates that folder2 appears to be inside folder1, but the structure is flat as far as all APIs are concerned.

The `NotesDatabase.EnableFolder()` method will create a folder.  (It's a dumb name for the method!)  Existing folders can be accessed via `NotesDatabase.GetView()` method because from the high-level API point of view Folder and Views are treated as equals.  The `NotesView.Remove()` method can be used to delete a folder. The `NotesView.Name` property is read/write.

Comment: Thank you very much for very usefull answer.
If there will be other newbies in VBA with Lotus Notes stuff, then the full procedure would be as follows:
1)You'll have to create a session through which you connect to notus db
(Set NSession = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")); 2) obtain the db from session (Set NMailDb = NSession.GetDatabase("YourDb", "Db.nsf")); 3) create folder (NMailDb.EnableFolder ("FolderName"))